# input, evdev alternatives?

Tags: xorg, input, input-method

Simply put what are some other input subsystems?

P.S. (a little context)
Is there a popular alternative? (I'm looking at an HP-UX and have no idea how its taking care of this, because there is no /dev/input/event*) and
based on the wiki Evdev is "closely related input driver for the X.Org Server" - can evdev exist without X.Org?

Comment: > my question(s) is(are) how are other systems doing this?
Doing what? Handling mouse/keyboard or handling multiple input devices of same type as one?

Comment: sorry, yes how are others handling the peripherals, Evdev - "...translates input events from peripheral-specific drivers into a generic structure which the input driver can easily translate into X11 events...", what are some input handling components, and how do they, well,handle input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole bunch of input drivers for X.Org http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/ (look for 'xf86-input-'). Ones that are typically used is `xf86-input-keyboard` and `xf86-input-mouse`. Multiplexing of many devices can be done either by some kernel-side things (like FreeBSD's [moused](http://man.freebsd.org/moused)+[sysmouse](http://man.freebsd.org/sysmouse) and [kbdmux](http://man.freebsd.org/kbdmux)) or by attaching all input devices to X.Org and managing them with XInput.